# R - time series plot displayed only in console, but not web app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write a simple RShiny app and here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(rAmCharts)

source("C:\\Users\\wluo\\Desktop\\Garch\\app\\curncy basket.R")
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "weight.plot"))

server <- function(input, output) {
        output$weight.plot <- renderPlot({
        date <- as.POSIXct(index(elasticd.w))
       amTimeSeries(data.frame(date, coredata(elasticd.w)), "date", c("CNH", "NTN", "SGD", "EUR", "JPY"),
                    groupToPeriods = c('hh', 'DD', '10DD'), main = "weights", legend = T, precision = 2)
      })
    }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When running the app, the plot produced by amTimeSeries is well shown in RStudio but the web app is blank. Can't figure out why.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the path for `curncy basket.R` correct for your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the **specific render and output functions of rAmCharts** (`renderAmCharts` and `amChartsOutput`). It wont work with plotOutput.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(rAmCharts)

# source("C:\\Users\\wluo\\Desktop\\Garch\\app\\curncy basket.R")
data('data_stock_2')

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(
  # plotOutput(outputId = "weight.plot"))
  amChartsOutput("weight.plot", height = "600px")
  ))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$weight.plot <- renderAmCharts({
    # date <- as.POSIXct(index(elasticd.w))
    # amTimeSeries(data.frame(date, coredata(elasticd.w)), "date", c("CNH", "NTN", "SGD", "EUR", "JPY"),
    #              groupToPeriods = c('hh', 'DD', '10DD'), main = "weights", legend = T, precision = 2)
    amTimeSeries(data_stock_2, 'date', c('ts1', 'ts2'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes that's the problem!! Thanks!